# ¿Por qué "medianoche" es un bollo en el que se coloca comida?

Tags: etimología, comida

[**Medianoche**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OkGmKdR) aparte del significado lógico de

> 1. f. Hora en que el sol está en el punto opuesto al de mediodía.

es también

> 2. f. **Bollo pequeño partido longitudinalmente en dos mitades, entre las que se coloca una loncha de jamón, queso, etc.**

y viene ya recogida en el diccionario de Rodríguez Navas de 1918, o en 1918 también se hace un juego de palabras con ella en "La venganza de Don Mendo" ("... fue vilmente traicionado y cambióse en media noche por no ser emparedado...")

¿Cómo surgió esa segunda acepción? ¿Tal vez como refrigerio que se servía a medianoche"?

Comment: Por lo que dice aquí es exactamente lo que has dicho, se servían en las fiestas sobre la medianoche: http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/medianoches-de-medianoche/

Comment: En la hemeroteca de la BNE hay ocurrencias [desde 1906](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/results.vm?o=&w=mediasnoches&f=text&t=%2Bcreation&l=600&l=700&s=0&lang=es): "té, helados, pastas, dulces, emparedados, croissants, mediasnoches, Jerez y Champagne".

Comment: Si alguien se anima que lo ponga como respuesta. Últimamente solo entro aquí desde el movil y me resulta incómodo para escribir y formatear bien las respuestas. Ando un poco liado y no participo mucho.

Answer (score 3):

> Hubo un tiempo en el que a las fiestas nocturnas que incluían música y baile se les llamaba saraos.
>
> En aquellos saraos, era costumbre servir, transcurrido un tiempo prudencial desde la cena, que se hacía bastante más temprano que ahora, una serie de bocaditos, más que nada como entretenimiento. Los más elegantes eran los que combinaban lo dulce con lo salado: unos bollos de leche, o suizos, en miniatura, partidos a lo largo en dos mitades entre las que se ponía algo salado.
>
> Esos minibocadillos **se servían en torno a la medianoche, y de ahí se pasó a llamarlos, justamente, medianoches.**
>
> Añadamos que el plural de medianoche es **medianoches**, y no *mediasnoches*
>
> <sub>Fuente: FundéuBBVA en [*Medianoches de medianoche*](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/medianoches-de-medianoche/)</sub>

De acuerdo a la fuente citada el bollito se llama así porque se solía servir a medianoche.

Comment: Tomo la palabra a @blonfu y he creado una respuesta para esta pregunta a partir del enlace que ha proporcionado él. Eso sí, es _community wiki_ así que cualquiera puede mejorarla si lo cree oportuno.